# Excel - Get the number of working hours which counts as night hours

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where I enter the start and finishing times of each shift. But during night shift you will earn 25% more, so I need to calculate the number of working hours which counts as night hours.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **start work** | **finish work** | **total hours** | **night hours** |
| 22:00 | 6:00 | 12:00 | ??? |
| . |  |  |  |
| **night shift start** | **night shift end** |  |  |
| 23:00 | 6:00 |  |  |

So far I have this formula:

```
=(REST(B2-A2;1))-((A2>B2)*MEDIAN(0;B2-1/4;16/24)+MAX(0;MIN(A5*24/24;B2+(A2>B2))-MAX(1/4;A2)))
```

It works but I cannot change the night shift end time.

Comment: 22:00 to 06:00 is not 12 hours (on my clock anyway)

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post